# Internal Storage with a file was working and now it is not

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I am in need of urgent help. I have an application that was working great just hours ago with writing and reading to an internal storage file. Now I'm home go to run it on my device and it starts force closing! This does not make any sense to me at all. My only guess is the file its trying to read is somehow not there now? I am trying to read and write to this file in numerous spots in the application. Here is a look at the error I received in LogCat.

```
    06-21 18:14:34.666: W/dalvikvm(5349): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wglxy.example.dash1/com.wglxy.example.dash1.F2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:65)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:59)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at com.wglxy.example.dash1.Grid.readRawText(Grid.java:214)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at com.wglxy.example.dash1.F2Activity.onCreate(F2Activity.java:75)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-21 18:14:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(5349):     ... 11 more
```

In my Grid class which contains the method readRawText, it is complaining about a certain line: InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(his).
"fis" was declared up above with a specific directory in mind.

Here is the code for that method of readRawText.....

```
public static String readRawText(Context context)
  {

      FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.wglxy.example.dash1/app_myDir/output.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

      InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
      BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
      String line;
      StringBuilder textFile = new StringBuilder();

      try
      {
          while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null)
          {
              textFile.append(line);
             // textFile.append('\n');

          }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          return null;
      }

      return textFile.toString();
  } 

}
```

Since the error it's giving me is a null pointer error I keep thinking that somehow the file could have disappeared or something.. I would be EXTREMELY grateful if someone could help me out with this. I just spent my whole day getting this application to work correctly and now it is not. It is just plain disheartening! You think you have something done, but you don't...

Again, I appreciate it if someone could tell me how to fix this or give me some valuable advice.

UPDATE HERE IS MY WRITEGRIDS METHOD IN F2Activity....

```
public void writeGrids(List<Grid> grids) throws IOException
{
    String data;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

     try
     {
     File dir = getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     Log.d("SEE",dir.getAbsolutePath());
     File myFiles = new File(dir, "output.txt");


     fos = new FileOutputStream(myFiles);




     for(Grid grid : grids)
     {
         data = grid.getGridNickName() + ";" + grid.getGridName() + ";" +
                  grid.getFirstName() + ";" + grid.getLastName() + ";" +
                  grid.getPassword()+ ";" + grid.getLoginURI() + ";"; 
         fos.write(data.getBytes());
     }
     }


      catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }

     fos.close();

}
```

so I'm guessing I need to put the piece of with File dir etc..... at the top of my code? But it shouldn't have to create a new file every time I run the program should it? I apologize if I sound ignorant. I'm fairly new to android and up until this point it's been a blast.

Comment: If you think the file is missing, check the file system to see if it is there, then report back.

Comment: Is your device connected to a computer with a usb cable? If so, what happens if you disconnect it?

Comment: Do you think it's because I'm using FileInputStream instead of openFileInput? I have no idea....I there any way I can physically see if the file is there?

Comment: I've check file explorer and gotten as far as data/data/com.wglxy.example.dash1, and then after that there are files called "files" and "lib" and "shared_prefs". "files" and "lib" have nothing whereas  "shared_prefs" has my shared preferences. Is there a way to get to that app_myDir folder??? Is that hidden or something? Also, the same error happens when connected to the device or when not.

Comment: @user1461393 : I've never explored internal storage but are you sure a  directory called `app_myDir` is a standard directory? If not then something somewhere else must have created it - presumably the code which created the `output.txt` file. Also, as an aside, don't hard-code file/directory paths - they're not guaranteed to be the same across different devices or Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a NullPointerException on the line

```
InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
```

You also are catching a FileNotFoundException when you are initializing your FileInputStream. My guess is that the FileNotFoundException is being thrown because the file simply doesn't exist causing the reference variable "fis" to be assigned to null.

Where does output.txt come from? Where is it created? Is there there a place in your app where the file /app_myDir/output.txt is being created that hasn't been reached at this point?

Also, to simply fix the problem of force closing, you need to check to see if "fis" is null. If it is not null, continue processing (this is a good practice even if you are relatively confident that the file is there):

```
if (fis != null) {
    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder textFile = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            textFile.append(line);
            // textFile.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return textFile.toString();
} else 
    return null;
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. Well, I found out where I create my infamous "output.txt". It's created in my writeGrids method in my F2Activity. It almost sounds exactly like I'm trying to read something before its been created. But then I don't understand why this worked a couple of hours ago. The directory "data/data/app_Dir is from when I use the getDir command in my writeGrids method. Let me edit and update the page to include my writeGrids method........

Comment: It could be that the file was deleted off of your device when you built the project. Then you didn't recreate it after rebuilding it.

Comment: That would certainly explain a lot. I need to do reading in writing in various forums. Where would you suggest I recreate my file? At the main screen?

Comment: It is probably fine being created where it is. The thing is though, every time you want to access the file, you need to check to see if it exists before you try to process it. I try not to create any databases or files unless the user gives the command to do so (i.e. not creating these resources as soon as the application is started), and if the user wants to perform an action that requires a file or database that does not exist yet, you just check to see if that resource exists, if it doesn't then inform the user that there is nothing there or handle it in some other way that you see fit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I am new when it comes to storing things in internal storage since I usually store everything in databases, but that's not what this app wanted. I am closer to solving the issue, thank you again.